# Carousel sliding for bunch of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="partTop">
      <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
      <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
  </div>
```

Next, I get all child divs from "partTop" like this:

```
this.$items = $('.partTop div');
```

And, finally, I set JQuery animation like this:

```
 _this.$items.stop().animate({'left': -100 + 'px'}
```

And here's a question: *if first element goes offscreen to the left, is there any way to force it to appear at right edge of the screen and resume animation by these 100 pixels?* Something like in carousel widgets.

I'm trying to google it and solve this problem by myself for a week, but seems I google it wrong. You can see what im trying to do here, with pretty messed up code: http://jsbin.com/hucac/2 As you can see, if first div goes offscreen to the left, he becomes last child of the *.partTop*, and here I need this carousel-thing.

P.S. Sorry for the terrible english guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element using jquery, and then append it to the container element using [appendTo](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/). For this to work you will have to make sure that you will only move the element when the animation is done.

Something along the lines of the following should probably work:

```
this.$items[0].appendTo($('.partTop'));
```

But why do this yourself when there are a thousand plugins that can do this for you?